# How do I notify-send a long command?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, vpn, notify-send

I want to use notify-send to show a notification every n minutes to tell me the vpn status.

The command would be running in a popup terminal I have already set up, hidden from view until I need to stop the while loop, then I'd just do ctrl-c.

I wrote the command below, but it errors out infinitely: `Invalid number of options.`

```
while true
do
    notify-send $(timeout 5s nordvpn status | rg -i "status|country|uptime" ; nordvpn settings | rg -i "kill switch|auto-connect")`
done
```

`timeout 5s` is there because sometimes nordvpn is not responsive, and I need to kill the command after 5 seconds.

Thank you for assisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command takes one or two arguments:

```
SYNOPSIS
       notify-send [OPTIONS] {summary} [body]
```

So, you'll simply wrap the result of your command in double quotes:

```bsh
while :; do
    notify-send "$(command)"
done
```